# Upstairs bathroom water leak flooded living room

Tags: bathroom, sealing

Yesterday I walked into the living room and it was literally raining. My houseguest had put a 'rag' in the upstairs bathroom sink, turned on the water and forgotten all about it. My couch and a recliner were soaked with almost an inch of water on the wood floor.

Today almost everything is dry. My wood floor has scrapes from me moving everything.

Now I need to find a way to stop this disaster from happening again. If I use Flexseal on my ceiling, the water will just soak into the wood floor and rot it. I'm very tempted to 'paint' the whole bathroom and put a 6" board across the threshold to enclose the whole half bath. Or I could just turn off the water to the sink and remove the line.

Comment: Normally the overflow slot in the sink should have allowed the water to drain.

Comment: What's your question? Unless you're the YMCA your bathroom shouldn't need to be a boat. Please revise to ask something clear and specific.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a water (leak) alarm, then at least it will get someone's attention if they forget.  They sound a lot like smoke alarms.  I personally have used this [alarm from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Basement-Watchdog-Battery-Operated-Water-Alarm-BWD-HWA/100038838).